# COMRESET failed code -16 with Ubuntu live USB

Tags: boot, hard-drive, live-usb

I am using a live USB to load Ubuntu onto a laptop with a dying hard drive. I am getting the following error:

```
[    2.697327] platform wdat_wdt: failed to claim resource 4
[    2.697332] ACPI: watchdog: Device creation failed: -16
[    13.158787] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[    22.195025] ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
[    32.226768] ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
```

After this error, the live system does continue to load.

This looks like a hard drive error, which is both understandable and not. That is, it is understandable that the hard drive would produce an error, because it is dying. However, I do not understand why an Ubuntu live USB is even touching the hard drive at all, since the install command was not issued.

Also, are these error codes actually listed anywhere you can look them up and see what they mean?

Comment: I experienced sinilar error, too